# Spring DataJPA not saving 3rd tabledata to the database

Tags: database, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have no problem with saving my entities to the database. However when I try to insert values into my 3rd many-to-many table, it simply doesn't do anything.
Here is my student entity;

```
@Table(name = "student", schema = "school")

public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long studentId;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "student_classroom", schema = "school")
    private Collection<Classroom> classroom = new ArrayList<>();
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(name = "student_teacher",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "studentId",
                            nullable = false, updatable = false)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id", referencedColumnName = "teacherId",
                            nullable = false, updatable = false)})
    private Set<Teacher> teachers = new HashSet<>();
```

The teacher entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher", schema = "school")
public class Teacher {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long teacherId;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "teacher_classroom", schema = "school")
    private Collection<Classroom> classroom = new ArrayList<>();
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "teachers", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();
```

Here is my service method.

```
public void addTeacherToStudent(long teacherId, long studentId) {
        Optional<Teacher> teacher = teacherRepository.findById(teacherId);
        Optional<Student> student = studentRepository.findById(studentId);
        student.get().getTeachers().add(teacher.get());
        teacher.get().getStudents().add(student.get());
    }
```

It has no problem saving the teachers and students in the sets in memory, however it doesn't reach the database. I have tried every annotation, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in Teacher entity

```
 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinTable(
            name = "student_teacher",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    )
  private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but thanks! it worked, I also added the @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tablename") on the other entity